# any better way to implement this

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

i was surfing the internet when i came across this algorithm(making change) and implemented it  as below...but still is there any efficient way to do this...also how can i find the complexity for the same from program i implemented...

1>algorithm is as follows

```
makechange(c[],n) //c will contain the coins which we can take as our soln choice and 'n' is the amount we want change for
soln<-NULL//set that will hold solution
sum=0
while(sum!=n)
{
    x<-largest item in c such that sum+x<=n
    if(there is no such item)
    return not found
    soln <- soln U {a coin of value x}
    sum=sum+x
    return soln
}

2>here is what i have tried

#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main() {
    int c[]= {100,50,20,10,5,1},soln[6];
    int num,i,j,sum=0,x,k,flag=0;
    clrscr();
    printf("\nEnter amount to make change:");
    scanf("%d",&num);

    for(i=0;i<6;i++) {
        soln[i]=NULL;
    }

    j=0;
    while(sum!=num) {
        for(i=0;i<6;i++) {
            if(sum+c[i]<=num) {
                x=c[i];
                break;
            }
        }

        sum=sum+x;
        for(k=0;k<6;k++) {
            if(soln[k]==x) {
                flag=1;
            }
        }

        if(flag!=1)
        soln[j]=x;
        j++;
    }

    printf("\nsoln contains coins below:");
    j=0;

    while(soln[j]!=NULL) {
        printf("%d ",soln[j]);
        j++;
    }
    getch();
}
```

any help would be appreciated...thank you...

Comment: `void main()`? Where did you learn this from?

Comment: "for(i=0;i<6;i++) { if(sum+c[i]<=num) { x=c[i]; break; } }" does not correspond to "x<-largest item in c such that sum+x<=n"

Comment: @modifiablelvalue but the program works...i am asking for the optimal way

Comment: @KaranMer then it should be migrated to [codereview.se]

Comment: how can i migrate it to code review...

Comment: You should search SO and the Web for other examples of this assignment.  It comes up frequently.

Comment: @KaranMer you click the flag button, select "Other" and enter "I think this should be migrated to code review" in the explanation box.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For fun, here's a `constexpr` version!

```
template <int... denomination>
    static constexpr auto change(int amount) -> decltype(make_tuple(denomination...))
    {
        typedef decltype(make_tuple(denomination...)) R;
        return R { [&]() { auto fill=amount/denomination; amount-=denomination*fill; return fill;}()... };
    }
```

Demo: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac1dd2aff77eedde)**

```
#include <boost/tuple/tuple_io.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using boost::tuple;
using boost::make_tuple;

template <int... denomination>
    static constexpr auto change(int amount) -> decltype(make_tuple(denomination...))
    {
        typedef decltype(make_tuple(denomination...)) R;
        return R { [&]() { auto fill=amount/denomination; amount-=denomination*fill; return fill;}()... };
    }

int main() {
    auto coins = change<100,50,20,10,5,1>(367);
    std::cout << coins;
}
```

Output:

```
(3 1 0 1 1 2)
```

Version without boost: http://liveworkspace.org/code/3uU2AS$0

> For absolute awesome, this is the disassembly of the [non-boost version](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3uU2AS%240) compiled by clang with -O2.
>   **http://paste.ubuntu.com/5632315/**
>
> Notice the pattern 3 1 0 1 1 2?
>
> ```
> 400826:   be 03 00 00 00          mov    $0x3,%esi
> ...
> 400847:   be 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%esi
> ...
> 400868:   31 f6                   xor    %esi,%esi
> ...
> 400886:   be 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%esi
> ...
> 4008a7:   be 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%esi
> ...
> 4008c8:   be 02 00 00 00          mov    $0x2,%esi
> ```
>
> It was completely compiletime evaluated!

Comment: My brain, it burrrrrrrns...

Comment: To be perfectly honest, the original code wasn't much clearer to me :) At least, functionally "fill", "amount", "denomination" tell me what is happening :)

Comment: So, that's an interesting loophole to circumvent current constexpr constraints (no declarations, no multiple statements, etc).

Answer (score 1):

The other approach is to go through the coin options, staring with the largest, and taking as many of those as you can without going negative, and then on to the next largest, and so on:

```
#define RESULT_EXACT   1
#define RESULT_INEXACT 0

int i;
int result_exact = RESULT_EXACT;

for (i=0; i<6; i++) {
    soln[i] = n/c[i]; // How many of this value do we need
    n -= soln[i]*c[i]; // We've now given that amount away
}

if (n!=0) result_exact = RESULT_INEXACT;
```

Obviously (I hope) this require that `c` stores the coin values from largest to smallest and requires a check on `result_exact` to know if the change is exactly correct.

Comment: yes exactly c is storing values from largest to smallest

Comment: You may want to try it against something like `n = 4` and `c = [ 3, 2 ]`. If the coin values aren't static, they normally aren't in these exercises, you will need a different approach

Comment: @Alexander fair point, flag indicating inability to do the impossible added.

Comment: @NeilTownsend, there are other cases though, `n = 8` and `c = [ 7, 2 ]`

Comment: @Alexander, you are, of course, correct. The question was about how to implement a particular algorythm most effectively, which I have tried to do with the answer. I have also flagged the question and suggested it should go to codereview, as I suspect that is where a question such as this is best placed. If you wish to engage in a question about the best way to solve this problem, perhaps it would be best to make that a separate question? Obviously I'm much newer on SO than you, so please do correct me if I'm getting something wrong here.

Comment: If the contest is "most efficiently" my answer might still have _some_ merit (besides being obviously over the top :)).

Comment: FWIW, I +1-ed this before even posting my own answer. Of course, your answer is more useful, and more explanatory... Cheers

Comment: @sehe thanks for the +1 - your answer is probably more efficient (assuming c++) - and delightfully over the top as you say!